# Why I get an error Java unclosed string literal?

Tags: java

I have a java class, but when I'm trying to build a project I get an error

```
error: unclosed string literal return load().query("""
                                                     ^
```

*(the third quote)*

Can you please explain to me why it is an error?

My code

```
@Component(ThreatImplMethodRepository.NAME)
public class ThreatImplMethodRepository extends DefaultRepository<ThreatImplMethod> {
    public static final String NAME = "gwf_ThreatImplMethodRepository";

    @Override
    protected Class<ThreatImplMethod> entityClass() {
        return ThreatImplMethod.class;
    }

    public List<ThreatImplMethod> getBySourcesAndTargets(List<ImpactSource> sources, List<ImpactTarget> targets, FetchPlan fetchPlan) {
        return load().query("""
                            select distinct im
                              from gwf_ThreatImplMethodLink imLink
                              join imLink.implMethods im
                             where imLink.source in :sources
                               and imLink.targets in :targets
                            """)
                .parameter("sources", sources)
                .parameter("targets", targets)
                .fetchPlan(fetchPlan)
                .list();
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Java? TextBlock is only standard in 15+.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, Zac Anger and user16320675 already mentioned this in the comments: you are using the Text Blocks feature<sup>1</sup>, which is probably not supported by your compiler.

The compiler parses `""` as an empty string literal and then reads the third one as an opening delimiter of another string literal, which is, according to the compiler, unclosed.

You are using the Text Blocks syntactical device, which is a feature since Java 15 (or since Java 13 as a *preview feature*).

Your code is working fine, but you'll need to use a Java ≥ 15 compiler.

---

<sup>1</sup> See [Java Language Specification § 3.10.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6) and its [JDK Enhancement Proposal #378](https://openjdk.org/jeps/378).